# Как связать один скрипт с другим скриптом являющемся компонентом prefab'a? Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в Unity в игровой сцене генерируется поле из клеток(шаблонов экземпляра). Скрипт HexClick является компонентом шаблона клетки и соответственно у каждой сгенерированной клетки своя собственная копия это скрипта. Когда я нажимаю на какую-либо клетку, скрипт данной клетки должен передавать координаты клетки другому скрипту HexPicked(который в одном экземпляре). Затем HexPicked должен установить у объекта к которому он привязан полученные координаты. То есть по итогу при нажатии на любую клетку на неё должен переместиться объект. Как это реализовать?
Я пытался делать через статические переменные, SerializeField, и просто через переменную public GameObject, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри. Если у тебя класс для каждой клетки достаточно специфичный, то можно в него добавить ссылку на тип компонента, который у тебя в единственном экземпляре.

```
public HexPicked hexPicked;
```

Если написать строчку выше, то у тебя в скрипте появится возможность передать туда GameObject с этим компонентом. А там уже дело техники.

Если у тебя что-то более конкретное, например сетка где-то создается и т.п. - дац знать, могу ответить более конкретно.

Comment: Проблема в том что я так и делаю но во вкладке компонента у prefab'a в поле для PickedHex можно поместить только другой prefab а просто игровой объект нельзя. HexClick ниже:                                                    public PickedHex picked:'public PickedHex picked;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        picked.SetTo(transform.position);
    }'                И когда я это делаю получается что координаты меняются у prefab'a, а я хочу чтобы они менялись у одного объекта в сцене.

Comment: По идее ты можешб получить список всех созданных GameObject-ов в children у родительского transform. Т.е. у тебя по идее все клетки сетки должны быть у определенного объекта и этот объект уже должен возвращать событие, что по определенной клетке нажали. Например получается, что у тебя будут классы Player, Cell и Grid. Grid. Каждый класс находится на своем GameObject-е. Притом все GO с компонентом Cell должны быть внутри GO с компонентом Grid. Grid должен взять transform.children и у всех у них подписаться на событие клика (можно даже на C#-ские). Далее остается только передать игрока Grid в ка